# Yii : How to select a sheet from excel?

Tags: php, excel, yii

Q : How to select a sheet from excel?

Status : I want the data from a xls/xlsx file. Now, I'm following via this [website](http://hafiznor.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/yii-read-excel-file-xlsx-format/). I've 3 sheets (G, H, I) at one excel file. I found getSheetByName() at PHPExcel class. When I tried by

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('I');
```

It give me an error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestRow() on a non-object

If I set 'G' ('G' is the first sheet at excel), it is working fine.

Thank you for your any advice.

Comment: may be that sheet(I) is not there in your excel file, can u add another sheet say J and now try to access I and look wht u get nw.

Comment: I changed the excel file format to 2007 and read again. show me this error "ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object".

Comment: We need more code - the error you're reporting does not correspond to the one line of code you've shown.